# Difference between Javascript and ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript

What is the difference between Javascript and ASP.net?

Comment: What is the difference between C++ and Visual Studio?

Comment: Since it was tagged as homework I gave him an up-vote

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Javascript  is a scripting language which runs in the browser while  ASP.net runs on the  server and is a framework for running web applications (you can compare it to JSP, ColdFusion etc etc) Just so you know....there are versions of ServerSide JavaScript( for the older among us.....remember Netscape's LiveWire?)

You can use Javascript   together with ASP.NET

Comment: +1 - commenting to emphasize Javascript is client side, ASP.net is server side, if you're processing data that you don't want to user to have access to you want to do it server side!

Answer (score 0):

the main and a basic difference is javascript is Browser side scripting language and ASP is server side scripting language.